# How to add only the necessary model in django to the second database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I use two databases in django, one is marked as "default", the other is optional. I have this question: I have a file with models, all these models are in the main database, and there is also another file models.py , I want to make migrations to the second DB from it. It's just that if I make migrations to it, then all the models in the project are added there, and I don't need it that way. So how to make it so that 1 model.py = 1 migration to an additional database?

Answer (score 0):

If i resume, you want to make migrations of some apps in a DB and some other apps in other DB ?

You have to use a custom DatabaseRouter for routing migrations and sql query to the good database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

After do that, you will be care about the `using` param in your queryset for executing sql which allow you to select the db: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api

Comment: I just want to add everything from models.py from the accounts application to the database (additional), but when I do migrations, ALL tables get there, even those that are in models.py in another application